# MonoTouch: Adding DLL references in sub projects

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, flurry, atmhud

In a way I am looking for best-practice here.

I have a common project that is shared by many of my apps. This project has FlurryAnaylics and the ATMHud DLLs as references.

If I do not also reference these DLLs in the main project, the apps will often, but not always, fail in the debug-to-device test. In the debug-to-simulator I don't need to add these DLLs to the main project.

So, the question is: Do I have to include references to DLLs in the main project that I have in sub projects all the time?

Comment: When you say it fail, exactly how does it fail? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: The app starts on the device in debug then explodes. The console just dumps a crash notice, no debugging info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever possible I use references to project files (csproj files) over references to assemblies (.dll). It makes a lot of things easier, like:

- code navigation (IDE);
- automatic build dependency (the source code you're reading is the one you're building, not something potentially out-of-sync);
- source-level debugging (even if you can have it without it, you're sure to be in-sync);
- (easier) switch between Debug|Release|... configurations;
- changing defines (or any project-level option);

E.g.

**Solution1.sln**

- Project1a.csproj
- MonoTouch.Dialog.csproj (link to ../Common/MonoTouch.Dialog.csproj)

**Solution2.sln**

- Project2a.csproj
- MonoTouch.Dialog.csproj (link to ../Common/MonoTouch.Dialog.csproj)

**Common.sln**

- MonoTouch.Dialog.csproj

Large solutions might suffer a bit from doing this (build performance, searching across files...). The larger they get the less likely everyone has to know about every part of it. So there's a diminished return on the advantages while the inconvenience grows with each project being added.

E.g. I would not want to have references to every framework assemblies inside Mono (but *personally* I could live with all the SDK assemblies of MonoTouch ;-)

**Note**: Working with assemblies references **should** not cause you *random* errors while debugging on device. If you can create such a test case **please** fill a bug report :-)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug, but when I don't include ATMHud.dll and FlurryAnalytics.dll in the main project, it fails. Adding references to these (I don't have source) makes the problem go away.

Comment: how do you add references to subprojects in MonoDevelop? In VisualStudio I "open solution" and check the box "add to current solution" on the open panel. I don't see how to do this operation in MonoDevelop.